# URLClassLoader throwing NullPointerException when loading class

Tags: java, android

Part of the (Android) app I'm working on requires a 'plugins' folder that users can drop their own code into, as a jar file. The app will scan the folder for jar files, and try to load all the classes it finds. Right now, the app is not loading any classes at all, because it seems all calls to URLClassLoader.loadClass() result in a null pointer.

```
private static URLClassLoader classLoader;
private static List<Class<? extends OpMode>> opModeList;

private static void attemptLoadClass(String entryname) {
    String classname = entryname.replace('/', '.');
    classname = classname.substring(0, classname.length() - 6);
    try {

        Class<?> c = classLoader.loadClass(classname);
        // ^^^ Problems are happening right here ^^^

        Object instance = c.newInstance();
        if (instance instanceof OpMode) {
            opModeList.add(((OpMode)instance).getClass());
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

classLoader is constructed with an array of URL's leading to all the jar files that will need to be loaded. I should also mention that the code only seems to throw inexplicable errors when it's running on an Android device, and not on my computer.

Comment: Forgot to initialize classloader itself, don't you?

Comment: classLoader is initialized in the function that calls attemptLoadClass()

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be saying that the NPE is thrown by this line of code:

```
    Class<?> c = classLoader.loadClass(classname);
```

If so, there is only one possible explanation: `classloader` is `null`.

Comment: The exception is not being thrown from that line, but rather from within that function call.

Comment: Show us the stack trace!  And the code that creates the classloader.